# How to use promises in NodeJs while processing files in the case below

Tags: javascript, node.js

I learn Javascript and I need some help with promises.

I have a code:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('mz/fs');

fs.readdir(__dirname)
  .then(function(filesNames) {
    return Promise.all(
      filesNames.map(fileName => fs.stat(fileName))
    )
  }) /*** after this, the file names are lost ***/
  .then(function(stats) {
    return stats.filter(stat => stat.isFile())
  })
  .then(function(stats) {
    return stats.reduce((sum, stat) => sum + stat.size, 0)
  })
  .then(console.log);
```

It calculates the total length of all files in a folder. The question is - what if I also need to read the files content? But after the first ".then()" file names are lost...

In short I need:

1. Read the list of files in a folder
2. Check the list and throw away folder names from it
3. Read each file in the list

Could you explain me how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the job of the function that return the `stat` to also return the filenames:

```
filesNames.map(fileName => {
    return fs.stat(fileName).then(stat => {
        return {name: fileName, stat: stat};
    });
});
```